# BigQuery's handling of missing fields and unknown/extra fields when importing JSON

Tags: json, google-app-engine, schema, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

The schema for my BigQuery table looks like:

```
A:STRING,B:STRING,C:STRING,D:STRING,E:STRING,F:STRING,createdAt:INTEGER,updatedAt:INTEGER,I:STRING
```

The file (JSON) in cloud storage has a single item and it looks like:

```
{
    "A": "AAA",
    "B": "BBB",
    "E": "EEEEE",
    "F": "FFFFF",
    "createdAt": 1364226047214,
    "XXXX": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "I": "IIIIII",
    "YYYY": {
        "Y1": 1.99,
        "Y2": "YYYYYY"
    },
    "location": {
        "city": "Amherst",
        "region": "NS",
        "country": "CA"
    },
    "purchaseDate": 1364225968000,
    "updatedAt": 1364226052634
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Errors:
Line:1 / Column:173, The field "createdAt" was not found on the current message.
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
```

Two questions related to the error above:

1. How does BigQuery deal with missing fields in data? Aren't all
   fields by default nullable?
2. How does BigQuery deal with unknown/extra fields in data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just tested your schema/data using the [webUI](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/) and got the following error:

```
Line:1 / Column:84, The field "XXXX" was not found on the current message.
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
```

1. Yes, fields are **nullable by default**. You need to explicitly define the field mode (nullable, required or repeated) if you want to change it. If a required field is missing in your JSON data you will get an error but if this same field is nullable it will work.
2. As you can see with the error on the "XXXX" field it will fail if your data contains extra fields. **Your data must match the table schema** as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#addmoredata), and you can't modify the table schema which is [immutable](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestionbestpractices#immutable) (you can find some informations [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#addmoredata) if you need to add fields by using another table)
3. Another thing that could be useful for people dealing with JSON data is that **each data row must be contained in a single line** in your file (like in [google example file](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/personsData.json)). If your json data is in a pretty formated form, data import will fail.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem this week, during last days I have been taking a look at the code and the problem was that that the BQ TableRow did not have all the elements that it was defined on the Big Query TableSchema.

Please re-check all the parameters you're adding on the TableRow and that this one is represented correctly on the TableSchema.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow :) Please familiarize yourself with how to post a good answer. Your answer should be a comment :)

Comment: @DawidPi I disagree. He specifies quite clearly what his solution was, when he had this problem. If this solves the problem it is an acceptable answer.